# Node JS MariaDB Program runs forever?

Tags: javascript, mariadb

The following program runs forever and never exits. It appears to hang when `conn.end()` is called. I have no idea why. This is taken from the [example code](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/). Why does it hang and never exit?

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');

const pool = mariadb.createPool({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'adminpassword',
    port: 3306,
    connectionLimit: 5,
    connectTimeout: 1000
});

async function asyncFunction() {
    let conn;
    try {
        console.log('get connection');
        conn = await pool.getConnection();
        const rows = await conn.query("SELECT 1 as val");
        console.log(rows);
        console.log('done with that');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('got error');
        throw err;
    } finally {
        if (conn) {
            console.log('please end');
            return conn.end();
        } else {
            console.log('nothing to end');
        }
    }

    console.log('exit?');
}

asyncFunction();
```

Comment: it's not a problem of maria DB. if you call an empty async function in the main thread, it won't exit either.

Comment: That's weird. I was doing the same thing with puppeteer and that exited ok. What should I be doing differently?

Comment: probably `(async () => await asyncFunction())()` will do it